# Get last modification date of drive in Python

Tags: python, usb-drive, last-modified

I'm trying to get the last modification date of a usb drive in Python. 
I am aware of [os.path.getmtime()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) and [os.stat()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat), but those only work on folders and files. When I run os.path.getmtime() on the usb drive's root path I get either "Mon Dec 31 23:00:00 1979" (on Windows 7) or a date in 1970 (on Linux).

Looping through the content and finding the most recently modified file won't help since I can modify the content of the drive by adding and removing files without actually changing their last modification date.

I need this because I am writing a script that requires the files and folders on the usb drive to be indexed in a database. This can take some time if there are many items, so I only want to re-index the content if it has changed since the drive was last used by the script.

**Edit** : the script plays audio files (from the USB drive or elsewhere), which aren't very likely to change. What really matters is to check whether the content of the drive has changed (if audio files and folders were added or deleted). The content gets indexed by the script because it needs a unique id for each file (on the USB drive or not) to make playlists.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I thought there was any easy way of doing this, but apparently there isn't. I found a workaround by forcing my script to look into a specific folder on the USB drive, which allows me to use os.path.getmtime().

Answer (score 0):

you could use the hashlib and glob libraries to loop thru the files and caclulate out a hash for each one and store it in a file somewhere.  then check the currently calced hash vs the previous one, if they are different perform the database update

Comment: Thank you but if I'm not mistaken this wouldn't catch changes like addition or deletion of files on the drive.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding the last modified file, just find the last "event" on the file using `max(os.lstat(file)[-3:])` :

```
import datetime
import os

volume = 'F:/'

#simply yelds all files in all subdirs of the volume
def all_files(volume):
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(volume):
        for filename in filenames:
            yield os.path.join(root, filename)

print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(max((max(os.lstat(file)[-3:]) for file in all_files(volume))))
```

works in my system (WinXP), I tried to modify create o copy/paste files in the volume.

Does not work with file ereasing.

Comment: Thanks, but I need something that takes any changes into account, including file deletion.

Comment: ..so I guess you can only store all the filenames + event dates in a file (or db), and check for any difference between last saved data and current one..

Comment: I have edited my question to provide more info on the context.